# Disable hover background color change on ion-button Ionic 2

Tags: button, colors, background, ionic2

I have three buttons. Two of them have changed background color by ngClass. When I hover one of the changed buttons, its background color changes back to default. How do I prevent this behavior?

My problem in images:

No hover image below:

[image]

 
Top left image hovered below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need add an class to your button

```
 <button ion-button  class="my-button">AS</button>
```

Then, you can set a color for your button hover in CSS:

```
.my-button:hover{
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also work with [Ionic Sass Variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/).

For your case, it would suffice to overwrite the three variables:

```
$button-ios-background-color-hover: your_color;
$button-wp-background-color-hover: your_color;
$button-md-background-color-hover: your_color;
```

In the file "theme/variables.scss"

Answer (score 0):

use !important keyword it will work 
for example

```
<button type="submit" class="btn2" (click)="openTabs()" ion-button block>U0 
-2-4 Rue  du Nord</button>
```

// css code is here //

```
.btn2:hover{
    background: #538455 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running ionic-angular version 3.9.2, I was able to disable the button hover using ionic class `disable-hover`